# Get data form into hook_node_insert / hook_node_update

Tags: 7, nodes

How to recover data from my form 'node' from the hook 'node_insert' or 'node_update'. Because I created a textfield and I can't see from the "$node" variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$node` object will be populated with the data from the form, the way for form is defined.

You can do something like this

```
hook_form($node, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['my_value'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    'title' => t('Some title'),
    '#default_value' => isset($node->my_value) ? $node->my_value : '',
  );

  ....

  return $form;
}
```

Then get the value on the node object.

```
hook_insert($node) {
  $my_value = $node->my_value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Values contained in the `$form_state['values']` array are copied in the `$node` from [entity_form_submit_build_entity($entity_type, $entity, $form, &$form_state)](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/entity_form_submit_build_entity/7), which is called by [node_form_submit_build_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit_build_node/7), the function called by the submission handler for the node edit form ([node_form_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.pages.inc/function/node_form_submit/7)).

The function is called as `entity_form_submit_build_entity('node', $node, $form, $form_state)`, and contains the following code:

```
  // Copy top-level form values that are not for fields to entity properties,
  // without changing existing entity properties that are not being edited by
  // this form. Copying field values must be done using field_attach_submit().
  $values_excluding_fields = $info['fieldable'] ? array_diff_key($form_state['values'], field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle)) : $form_state['values'];
  foreach ($values_excluding_fields as $key => $value) {
    $entity->$key = $value;
  }
```