# Get form values into hook_node_insert / hook_node_update

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

I need to get in `hook_node_insert` and `hook_node_update` the value of a field I manually added to a form.

```
function hook_form_FORMID_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $formState, $form_id) {

  $form['newfield'] = [
    '#title' => 'New field',
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
  ];
}
```

In Drupal 7 every form field is copied to the entity and it's easy to access it as explained here [Get data form into hook_node_insert / hook_node_update](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/get-data-form-into-hook-node-insert-hook-node-update)

Is there a way in Drupal 8 too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an entity builder callback on the form, for example:

```
function menu_ui_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // ...
  $form['#entity_builders'][] = 'menu_ui_node_builder';
}

/**
 * Entity form builder to add the menu information to the node.
 */
function menu_ui_node_builder($entity_type, NodeInterface $entity, &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $entity->menu = $form_state->getValue('menu');
}
```

Comment: It works despite I get the warning "Field declared dynamically", but I can live with it :)

Comment: Well, depending on what you do with it, you can also just use a regular submit callback, you can access the entity with $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity() for an entity form. Only use this if you actually need that information to be able during the hooks and then maybe consider to just make it a field..